# Google Analytics API login causes security breach due to web server IP change

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I access my Google Analytics account from a web server through Google's API and poll Analytics for stats for a web site I have.

This has been running smoothly for a couple of years, but recently the hosting company moved the VPS that runs the site from one server to another and as a consequence the IP number of the server changed.

The Google account system immediately shut down access from the new server/IP address and it has been unable to fetch data since then.

I can easily make it work locally from a local server (in Denmark), but the production server is in the US and has been blocked. I have tried all kinds of wizardry and followed all the instructions I could find, confirmed that the login was me on my Google account security settings and whatnot, but Google keeps on bouncing me and sending me alerts about suspicious login attempts, and even tells me after each login attempt:

“For your security, we will continue to display these events for 2 weeks.”

And it seems that these 2 weeks never end, because I have tried numerous times during the last month or so, and it simply resets and keeps on going no matter how much I try to confirm that my server is legit.

I have found one possible remedy, but not really a useful one, which asked me to go to a certain page from the IP address in question and confirm my identity. Google would then register the address as OK. But since the machine is physically in the US and I'm in Denmark, and since it's a web server and not a client machine, that is a problem. I could maybe do it through a remote SSH terminal and browse the Google page using Lynx or something, but I have no idea whether that would work.

The method is mentioned here: 
https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257?p=client_login&rd=1

Is there any method that allows me to add the server's IP number from my current position where I have full and unrestricted access?

Martin

Comment: With which version of API you are fetching your data and how.
for instance in v3 version we just needed to integrate public key file with our server application and it didn't manner on which location it is hosted

Comment: Kamran, I can't remember which version I use. But it's most likely an older one. I coded the feature a year or two ago, so it might have changed since then. I'll look into the public key feature. That would probably solve the problem. Thanks for the input.

Comment: You are welcome Martin.Let me know if you need any help for implementing it

Answer (score 1):

Try going to
https://security.google.com/settings/security/activity
and look for a line like this:

9:07 AM Application/device sign-in attempt (prevented)  United States

It should give you the option to allow future attempts from that server.

Even then you may still have issues (I just did). The next step is to go here:
https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754?hl=en

and "clear the captcha". Whatever that means. But it worked for me.